# How to serve same web app on multiple domain subpage?

Tags: nginx, server, dns

Let's say I have two website :

- foo.com
- bar.com

These two websites would have a different content on the main page. However I'd like both to serve the same web app when reaching the following url :

- foo.com/app
- bar.com/app

The app is hosted on its own server. I am not too sure where to ask this question since I don't know if the desired result is possible or not.

**Update 2020-08-09**

Still looking for help on the topic. There seems to be mixed response. At the moment I am trying to figure out the best option to achieve the result. Someone pointed toward subdomains which I can do, but I'd still like to be able to reach the app through foo.com/app

Comment: It's substantially easier if you can do something like `app.foo.com` and `app.bar.com`. Otherwise you potentially get into proxies and whatnot.

Comment: What should I start reading if I'd still go for the multiple domains solution over the sub domains ? Any hint / article ?

Comment: Would pointing foo.com to app.foo.com be a good starting point ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't have pages from different domain point to the same web app hosted on another server

Answer (score -3):

No it is not possible to do what you're asking sorry.

Comment: It's absolutely possible, if a bit complicated. There are usually *better* ways.

Comment: I'd like to know about the "better ways" or alternatives you are thinking of.